# Lambda expression to check even numbers

Tags: java, lambda

I wrote this code to check the even numbers from the `List`. After finding even number I `twice` the even numbers with the help of `Map` and then find the sum of each even number after making it double by use of the `reduce` method.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public static void main(String[] args) {
List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);

System.out.println(
numbers.stream()
        .filter(e -> e % 2 == 0)
        .map( e -> e * 2)
        .reduce(0, Integer::sum));
}
```

Comment: Try to express the desired sum as formula of your N of the integer range and you don't need no Lambdas at all :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you come across the [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html)?  I'd use that for numerical operations rather than the boxed version `Stream<Integer>`.

Comment: `System.out.println(numbers.stream().filter(e -> e % 2 == 0).mapToInt( e -> e * 2).sum());` I change the `map` to `mapToInt` and remove that box `Integer::sum` to `sum()`.

Comment: Or one step further (assuming the `List` is not absolutely necessary): `IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 9).filter(e -> e % 2 == 0).map(e -> e * 2).sum()`